# How to logout of app in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone

I am doing an app in which on startup of App,a tabbarController with Search and Login views will be presented.When I click on Search tabbaritem SearchView wil appear.When Login tabbaritem is clicked Login view will appear ..When the Login is successful a tabbarcontroller with Four tabbaritems(Search,MyProfile,MyActivities,Logout)will appear.Now when I click on logout I have to logout of  the account and I need to show again the startup view.

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: It's about programming logic. Hard to tell if you are not sure what you created when you login. **what have you tried**? last, please accept more answers.

Comment: @sosborn Hi sosborn, I dont know what architecture you are using, but pretty sure that you are having tabbarcontoller as the top most handler of the application, and if it is so, then no doubt you must be having the object of That tabbarcontroller in your app delegate, so just go to the appDelegate class create your logout method (which would be calling by logout button) and add logic empty tabbarController.viewControllers and come to the beginning point of  the application.

Comment: @nick, thanks but I'm not the one who posted the question.

Comment: @sosborn sorry for that,just saw your name and not his and posted it to you.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its related with your application architecture. i would like to divide your question :

I m pretty much new to objective-C and I m doing an app in which on startup of App,a tabbarController with Search and Login views will be presented.

**Reply: Initially you need to have a navigation controller in the AppDelegate which will work like a parent navigation controller and you need to add your tabbar controller as a rootviewcontroller to it, it will help to get out of the second tabbar controller when you want to logout.**

When the Login is successful a tabbarcontroller with Four tabbaritems(Search,MyProfile,MyActivities,Logout)will appear

**Reply: Now when you get logged in then you will push a new tabbar controller with 4 tabs, it will get pushed on the parent navigation contrller (that we created in app deleate)  .**

Now when I click on logout I have to logout of the account and I need to show again the startup view

**Reply: Now when you want to logout and after doing all the logout related stuff(like closing the session etc) if you want to pop the view controller like `[self.navigationController popViewController]` it will not going to help you. as the self.navigation controller is the navigation controller of the new tabbar (of 4 tabs, that you pushed after login ). So you need to access the parent navigation controller here, which we created in app delegate into the Logout view controller, like : `[appDelegate.navController poptoRootViewController]`  .**

So the important point here is you need to have access and control over the parent navigation controller.

Hope this helps.